# Iterating over array of values in parameterized query

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to pass array of values to parameterized query and iterate over the values then pass the results to data frame. However when I run the script I got only first value from the array in the resulted data frame. I am not sure where might be the problem. The code is:

```
from numpy import array
import pandas as pd

PROJEC_ID = 'prj_id'

input_array = array(['CZ', 'SK'], dtype=object)

query = """
 SELECT country, ROUND(sum(tvr_yr_month),0) as PublicSales from `` 
 WHERE country IN UNNEST(@s) 
 GROUP BY country
"""

query_config = {
    'query': {
        'parameterMode': 'NAMED',
        'queryParameters': [
            {
                'name': 's',
                'parameterType': {'type': 'ARRAY',
                                  'arrayType': {'type': 'STRING'}},
                'parameterValue': {'arrayValues': [{'value': i} for i in input_array]}
            }
        ]
    }
}

result = pd.io.gbq.read_gbq(query, project_id=PROJEC_ID, dialect='standard',
                            configuration=query_config)
print(result.to_string())
```

The result look like this:

```
       country        PublicSales 
0      CZ              1272308.000000000
```

Any suggestions why SK is missing?

Answer (score -1):

I just went the other way around and iterated over dataframe from the query results and spread the results as I needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, according to stackoverflow guidelines, this does not count as an answer. Instead, this is what we call a comment, please use the comment box instead. If you can't use the comment box due to reputation requirements, please answer questions that do not require commenting to gain enough reputation over time.

Comment: @AmaanK: Since they are the OP, they can comment on their own posts independent of reputation. That said, this does provide a hint of an answer—it really just needs an [edit] to provide more details.